# Почему не создается компонент?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вроде все предельно просто но почему label не создается на форму, форма по счету является 3й, но это не имеет значение

```cs
private void Load_components(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label label = new Label();
   this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: и да хочу уточнить что проблема не в том что я label-у не указал текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извиняюсь за такую глупую ошибку, проблема в том, что метод `Load_components(object sender, EventArgs e)` был создан вручную, данный метод не был подписан на соответствующее событие, и не был создан автоматически (при двойном клике на событие), поэтому метод нигде и не вызывался.

Comment: странный ответ.

Comment: Я так полагаю, что метод написан руками и нигде "автоматически" не вызывался (по типу Form_Loaded)